# WebdriverIO update results in browserStack API call does not wait for response

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have setup my tests using webdriverIO V5 and Browserstack. The tests run successfully, however the test results are not being updated in the BrowserStack . The request call that I have made in my code does not wait for it to complete

in my wdio.conf.js , I have the following code:

```
afterTest: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
        let sessionid = browser.sessionId;
        if (!test.passed) {
            request({
                uri: `https://${this.user}:${this.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${sessionid}.json`,
                method: 'PUT',
                form: { 'status': 'error', 'reason': "" }
            })      
        }
        else {
            request({
                uri: `https://${this.user}:${this.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${sessionid}.json`,
                method: 'PUT',
                form: { 'status': "passed", 'reason': "" }
            })
        }
//browser.pause(3000)
```

Results are updated only when I give the browser.pause(3000).
How can I make this to wait till the request has been completed rather that waiting for 3 seconds after every test

Comment: Hi, Could you please help us where the `request()` method belongs to? is it `request` node-module? And is the above code in `wdio.conf.js` file? On high-level i can see you are missing to handle the asyn behavior here. Please give this info and i should able to help you

Comment: @NaveenThiyagarajan- please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NaveenThiyagarajan - request() is from node_module. The above code is in wdio.conf.js file. I was able to get it working with async . is there a better way to do this? below is my code:

```
var request = require("request");

exports.config = {
    afterTest: async function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
        let sessionid = browser.sessionId;

        function doRequest(url, testStatus) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                request({
                    uri: url,
                    method: 'PUT',
                    form: { 'status': testStatus, 'reason': "" }
                }, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        resolve(body)
                    }
                    else {
                        reject(error)
                    }
                })
            })
        }

        if (test.passed) {
            let res = await doRequest(`https://${this.user}:${this.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${sessionid}.json`, "passed")
            console.log(res)
        }
        else {
            let res = await doRequest(`https://${this.user}:${this.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${sessionid}.json`, "error")
            console.log(res)
        }
    },
}
```